# Getting a MS build fatal error during Visual Studio Install

Tags: visual-studio

I tried to install Visual Community and it hung so I uninstalled what components were out there and re-installed.  Now I am getting this error:  Installed could not continue because required component failed.  Any help is appreciated.  I did reboot and re-installed and still get the message.  Thx. This is my log:

```
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:08]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:08]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:08]i319: Applied execute package: VCRedistD11x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:08]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: netfxfullredist_43
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:08]i301: Applying execute package: netfxfullredist_43, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\NetFxIsv394271\packages\dotNetFramework\dotNetFx-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\NetFxIsv394271\packages\dotNetFramework\dotNetFx-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" IgnorePendingReboot=1 /q /norestart /KeepAUPaused /ChainingPackage vs_community  /log "C:\Users\NEWUSE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20170116110126_008_netfxfullredist_43.log.txt"'
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: netfxfullredist_43 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 547434496  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 145502208
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i319: Applied execute package: netfxfullredist_43, result: 0x0, restart: None
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {79B9B6C9-3FAF-4F50-96A9-C1651EA0DD31}, version: 1.0.25420.01, package: vs_vshubcore
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i325: Registering dependency: {79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2} on package provider: {79B9B6C9-3FAF-4F50-96A9-C1651EA0DD31}, package: vs_vshubcore
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:51]i301: Applying execute package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6BF8837D-67E1-4359-89FB-C08BFD6F2138}v14.0.25420\packages\BuildTools_MSBuild_x86\BuildTools_MSBuild.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86) failed: Error Message Id: 1304 ErrorMessage: Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory.
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 770048  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 352256
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory. Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory., Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i319: Applied execute package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i318: Skipped rollback of package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory. Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i319: Applied rollback package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[14C4:15D0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 345705218048  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 861200384
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 344854036480 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 344854036480 bytes
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_community
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.25420.01.00
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.25420
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P5 - Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_x86
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P8 - Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory.
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P9 - 
[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: `[1AEC:1AF0][2017-01-16T11:09:56]i000: MUX:  P8 - Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, especially with the last message
"Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory."

The error message is completely wrong and misleading.

The real cause is a missing installation of Microsoft .NET 4.5.2
which you can download from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42642

After I downloaded and installed that (choose the language you need, of course),
installation completed.